# How to reach my ethereum wallet?

Tags: transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I have an Ethereum wallet address, but I don't know from which platform.  How can I find out were my wallet is from?

Comment: Do you have a keystore file or private key from your address?

Comment: When you say 'address' do you mean the public key?

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to have the private key, seed, or keystore file (all which are generated on wallet creation) to access your ethereum wallet. If you've lost these then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public key/address (the visible key you share with others/ view on a block explorer) then you cannot decern any info about the wallet that was used to create the address.